# I (had to work) late yesterday evening

Tags: exam-questions

Can anyone help me answering that? I think the answer is "I had to work" is it right?

I (must work/have to work/work/had to work) late yesterday evening.

Comment: We don't do homework here. Please. Try each combination in Word and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly right. ***must*** and ***have*** are present-tense verbs. ***had*** is the past-tense form of ***have*** and since we are talking about something that happened in the past (yesterday evening), you should say ***I had to work***. ***had*** is also commonly used in situations where you want to express the idea that you "must" do something but in the past. This is because ***must***, as is typical for certain modals in English, lacks a past-tense form.